# Angularjs : Error occur after install angular cli using yarn

Tags: angularjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to install angular CLI using yarn, for some reason because npm installation of angular CLI has also error don't know why. that's why i'm trying to use yarn

tried this command:

```
yarn global add angular-CLI
```

and the error is this :

```
test@test-X455LAB ~ $ yarn global add angular-cli
yarn global v1.2.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been renamed to 
@angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
warning angular-cli > remap-istanbul > istanbul > fileset > 
minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid 
a RegExp DoS issue
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. 
Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "http://registry.npmjs.org/isobject: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/test/.config/yarn/global/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

what seems to be the problem? thanks

Comment: The problem is that angular-cli has been renamed to 
@angular/cli, and that you should thus not install angular-cli, which is completely obsolete, for quite a long time. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation. The other problem is that there appears to be trouble with your network connection.

Comment: Read error message, everything is written there. `update your dependencies`

Comment: Hi thanks for the response guys. But sir vicjordan how am i suppose to do that?